# How do I use files on AWS S3 for making RDS instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have uploaded a ".sql" file (which I made by converting an excel file using convertcsv.com) to the AWS S3 bucket. Now I want to run that file on an RDS instance. How do I do that?

`CREATE TABLE mytable(
   PassengerId INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,Survived    BIT  NOT NULL
  ,Pclass      INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Name        VARCHAR(82) NOT NULL
  ,Sex         VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
  ,Age         NUMERIC(4,2)
  ,SibSp       INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Parch       INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Ticket      VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL
  ,Fare        NUMERIC(8,4) NOT NULL
  ,Cabin       VARCHAR(15)
  ,Embarked    VARCHAR(1)
);
INSERT INTO mytable(PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked) VALUES (1,0,3,'Braund, Mr. Owen Harris','male',22,1,0,'A/5 21171',7.25,NULL,'S');`

The .sql file is basically like this with multiple inserts later on.

Comment: What kind of SQL Statements are there in the .sql file?

Comment: Just edited the question to include sample code from the sql file. It is the famous titanic db in case you were wondering.

Comment: RDS are database instances where database servers are hosted. You should think about writing a code which downloads the file from S3, connects to the database and run the contents of the file as SQL statements against the database.

Comment: Other way to do is connect to the database from your local machine using SQL Management studio (if RDS is SQL Server) or MySQL Workbench (if RDS is MySQL) and Open the sql file in them and run it.

Answer (score 0):

other way of doing this is using AWS Data Pipeline where it using a predefined template you can insert data from S3 location into RDS Instance

**Create a Pipeline and select a predefined template**

[image]

**Define Source Input S3 File location and Destination table details**

[image]

[AWS Reference steps for creating a Data Pipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-importexport-ddb-console-start.html)